# How can I get ACRA working with Phonegap on Android?

Tags: android, cordova

I have a PhoneGap application that works fine but occasionally is known to have bugs. I would like to catch them and send them to a Google Doc with ACRA

I have been following the ACRA wiki steps here http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/BasicSetup?tm=6

The ACRA documentation says I should create an Application class and then point my AndroidManifest at it by naming the Application the same as that class.
That didn't work, or at least it didn't catch any errors I tested it with.

I thought this would be the best bet, but it isn't logging anything and still Force Closes the app when I force a NullPointer exception error.

```
@ReportsCrashes(formKey = "dFhqOGY3cVVGc0w4UUxGa2E2Y3RL...",
        mode = ReportingInteractionMode.NOTIFICATION)
public class myPhoneGap extends DroidGap
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
         ACRA.init(this.getApplication());
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         super.init();
         super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you have to set up another activity that extends Application like this:

```
 package jq.test;

 import android.app.Application;
 import org.acra.*;
 import org.acra.annotation.*;

 @ReportsCrashes(formKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx") 
 public class MyApplication extends Application {

 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // The following line triggers the initialization of ACRA
        ACRA.init(this);
        super.onCreate();
    }

 }
```

and then in your manifest change the name of the application to the name of the class. I'm pretty sure that that's it but I have a question for you.....how do you get the formkey from Google Docs? I can't remember how to do that lol and its not posted anywhere. It really should be in the acra wiki but its not.

Comment: You get the formkey after you have published by going to the Form menu  -> Edit Form and in the popup you can copy the formkey value from the bottom of the screen

Comment: Yeah i found it after looking over and over. I dont know why I missed it but for some reason I passed over it like 20 times.